# Why is getLocalMillis() of LocalTime in Joda Time is a protected method?

Tags: java, jodatime

I wanted to convert joda time LocalTime to millis or milliseconds. I saw that the getLocalMillis is a protected method. Looks like there is no method to get the millis value of LocalTime.

So, do I have to get the values of each field in millis and then add them up to get the total millis ? Why does Joda Time not have a public method for getting Local Millis ?

Comment: `a public method for getting Local Millis`? What would you expect the method to return? The milliseconds from start of the day, or from the epoch?

Comment: @leonbloy - Well, I learned new things from the answer below. When I did not know those things, I was expecting milliseconds from epoch to LocalTime.

Comment: And what with those "Keywords for search engine"? Please remove that

Comment: @leonbloy - it makes the post easy to find. I will edit it.

Comment: Maybe related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665404/simplest-way-to-get-local-milliseconds-in-a-time-zone-with-joda-time

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `LocalTime` does not represent an absolute instant in time, but rather it describes a time of any day for an arbitrary timezone.

Render your `LocalTime` into an `DateTime` via [`LocalTime#toDateTimeToday()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#toDateTimeToday%28%29) or [`LocalTime#toDateTimeToday(DateTimeZone)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#toDateTimeToday%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) if you're looking for the moment described by that time today. Or if you want that moment on another day, construct the appropriate `LocalDate` and see the [`LocalDate#toDateTime(...)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTime%28org.joda.time.LocalTime%29) methods.  Then call `DateTime#getMillis()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use also `.toDate().getTime()`

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the time milliseconds, you can also do:

```
LocalTime#get(DateTimeFieldType.millisOfDay())
```