# Jodatime: Getting milliseconds from date yields "Illegal instant"

Tags: date, parsing, jodatime

```
  val date = "01-10-1967"
  val pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
  val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)
  formatter.parseMillis(date) // this line fails
```

The last line fails with:

```
Cannot parse "01-10-1967": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires)
```

Any idea why?

(JodaTime version is 2.3)

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5451152/2015911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st of October 1967 was in Argentina a day where they [changed from standard time to summer time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/argentina/buenos-aires), i.e. added 1 hour, on 00:00.

Since you are not providing a concrete time, I would assume that it defaults to exactly 00:00 which simply did not exist on that day.

Cf. [the official faq](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#illegalinstant):

> What does 'Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition' mean?
>   Joda-Time only allows the key classes to store valid date-times. For
>   example, 31st February is not a valid date so it can't be stored
>   (except in Partial). The same principle of valid date-times applies to
>   daylight savings time (DST). In many places DST is used, where the
>   local clock moves forward by an hour in spring and back by an hour in
>   autumn/fall. This means that in spring, there is a "gap" where a local
>   time does not exist. The error "Illegal instant due to time zone
>   offset transition" refers to this gap. It means that your application
>   tried to create a date-time inside the gap - a time that did not
>   exist. Since Joda-Time objects must be valid, this is not allowed.

Possible solutions might be (taken from the faq):

- Use `LocalDateTime`, as all local date-times are valid.
- When converting a `LocalDate` to a `DateTime`, then use `toDateTimeAsStartOfDay()` as this handles and manages any gaps.
- When parsing, use `parseLocalDateTime()` if the string being parsed has no time-zone.

Since you aren't interested in time information anyway, I think you might even want to replace `formatter.parseMillis(date)` with `formatter.parseLocalDate(date)`. If for some reason you still need milliseconds, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665404/simplest-way-to-get-local-milliseconds-in-a-time-zone-with-joda-time) might help.

Comment: it's a birth date and I really don't care about the hours and minutes. what would be the correct way of getting the epoch time?

Comment: Thanks Marvin, I came up with this but it's still failing with the same error:

`parseLocalDate(date).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(ArgTimezone).getMillis`

Comment: `formatter.parseLocalDateTime("01-10-1967").toDateTime().getMillis()` works for me. It's a bit hard to predict where you're aiming at, though - there might be easier ways for your needs.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a timestamp for a birth date, since the db field is an integer.

Comment: Thanks again for the insights. That same code is failing for me, perhaps because my timezone is `(America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires)` and your's is different? I guess you could resume the problem like this **given a date with format dd-MM-yyyy, return the epoch representation of first time of that day (in Argentina/GMT-3)**

Comment: Thought I had the time zone manually set to Argentina (and I could verify the exception with your initial approach). I'll have to double-check, I don't have the sources here right now.

Comment: with your guidance I found the solution, it works using `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` a particular code path didn't call that method, it's fixed now. **thanks so much!!**